# LIKE Query in JPA using List of String - Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Have used containing method in repository for %LIKE% SQL equal in JPA, as below,

```
Page<Obj> findByNameContaining(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

which will work like below,

```
select * from Obj where name like '%John%';
```

But how do i pass the `List<String>` names which would query like below using JPA,

```
select * from Obj where name like '%John%' or name like '%Jiva%' or name like 'etc' .....;
```

Is there any Spring JPA way for this? i also checked Specification classes too, is that the only way of doing this or am i missing any easy ways or any other dynamic query is recommended?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497673/how-to-use-multiple-like-keyword-in-sping-jpa-on-same-column

Comment: @zappee this i have already looked and its for IN clause with SET values. But my requirement is performing %LIKE% operation in same column with list<String> values, and the matching query for the sql i have placed in the question. Though LIKE and IN are not same so

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167730/dynamic-named-query-in-entity-class-using-jpql-example) one, OR [paragraph 9 of this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) can help. Please check them.

Answer (score 2):

The most Spring Data JPA way to do this is to use a `Specification` which adds a like-predicate for every element in the list.
You would call it like so

```
repository.findAll(containingOneOf(listOfNames))
```

with `Specification containingOneOf(List<String> listOfNames)` is a method you need to create.

See https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/ for more details about specifications in Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create a query with multiple `like` operator inside a repository interface But there is a workaround to do this using `EntityManager`.

`EntityManager` is extensively used in [SimpleJpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html). We can get instance of this class using `@PersistenceContext` like this:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and call its method `.createQuery(QUERY).getResultList()` to execute a database call. For pagination , You can check this [Pagination using entity manager in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703308/implementing-pagination-using-entity-manager-in-spring)

To create query you can write a simple logic like this:

```
String createQuery(List<String> names){
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select e from Employee e where ");
    int size = names.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        query.append("e.name like '%").append(names.get(i)).append("%'");
        if(i != size-1){
            query.append(" OR ");
        }
    }
    return query.toString();
}
```

In the above code , `Employee` is my entity class for which i am creating a select query with multiple `like` operator.

Complete code:

```
List<Employee> getEmployees(List<String> names){
    String query = createQuery(names);
    return entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: One should be extremely careful when assembling query Strings because they a susceptible of SQL injection attacks..